# Looking for a free "Feature Request/Vote" system in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vote

I'm looking for a free asp.net system or component which allow my users to make feature requests and vote for existing ones.

It's for internal use (a non profit organization - with "old" users ;)). Users shouldn't need to log in to be able to suggest a feature or vote.

The StackOverflow has a really great - and SIMPLE - UI. Would love something similar...

Do you know if a such system or component exists ? I haven't found any yet...

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst not exactly components, you can integrate one of the following user feedback services into your site:

- [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/) (free - look for "Start a free community" on plan page)
- [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/) (free)

They both allow collection of user feedback and voting.

Comment: Woow ! They both seem to be really great. Will study that. What a pity that they are only online services. But could do the trick. Thanks !

Comment: @JYL I see that UserVoice has [a great REST API](http://developer.uservoice.com/).

Comment: @Jeff : thanks for pointing that out. I'm using UserVoice for months and it's really great. I don't think I'll use the API as it's not required for me for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ASP.NET [ToggleButton control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx). That would cover the up and down arrows (with the proper up and down, selected/deselected images). You would just need to wire it up to save the counts for up and down selections and display the total number in between.

Comment: I'll need to build myself the entire system with this one. I hoped a more "ready-to-use" system or component... But thanks for answer !